# Problem with jquery ajax form on Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter

Everytime I test the email is send correctly. (I have tested in PC: IE6, IE7, IE8, Safari, Firefox, Chrome. MAC: Safari, Firefox, Chrome.)

The _POST done in jquery (javascript). Then when I turn off javascript in my browser nothing happens, because nothing is _POSTed.

```
Nome: Jon Doe
Empresa: Star 
Cargo: Developer
Email:  jondoe@test.com
Telefone: 090909222988
Assunto:  Subject here..
```

But I keep recieving emails like this from costumers:

```
Nome:
Empresa:
Cargo:
Email:
Telefone:
Assunto:
```

---

**CONTACT_FORM.PHP**

```
    <form name="frm" id="frm">                
    <div  class="campoFormulario nomeDeCampo texto textocinzaescuro" >Nome<font style="color:#EE3063;">*</font></div>
    <div  class="campoFormulario inputDeCampo" ><input class="texto textocinzaescuro"  size="31" name="Cnome" id="Cnome" value=""/></div>


    <div  class="campoFormulario nomeDeCampo texto textocinzaescuro" >Empresa<font style="color:#EE3063;">*</font></div>
    <div  class="campoFormulario inputDeCampo" ><input class="texto textocinzaescuro"  size="31"  name="CEmpresa"  id="CEmpresa" value=""/></div>

    <div  class="campoFormulario nomeDeCampo texto textocinzaescuro" >Cargo</div>
    <div  class="campoFormulario inputDeCampo" ><input class="texto textocinzaescuro"  size="31"  name="CCargo" id="CCargo" value=""/></div>

    <div  class="campoFormulario nomeDeCampo texto textocinzaescuro" >Email<font style="color:#EE3063;">*</font></div>
    <div  class="campoFormulario inputDeCampo" ><input class="texto textocinzaescuro"  size="31"  name="CEmail" id="CEmail" value=""/></div>


    <div  class="campoFormulario nomeDeCampo texto textocinzaescuro" >Telefone</div>
    <div  class="campoFormulario inputDeCampo" ><input class="texto textocinzaescuro"  size="31"  name="CTelefone" id="CTelefone" value=""/></div>

    <div  class="campoFormulario nomeDeCampo texto textocinzaescuro" >Assunto<font style="color:#EE3063;">*</font></div>
    <div  class="campoFormulario inputDeCampo" ><textarea class="texto textocinzaescuro"  name="CAssunto" id="CAssunto" rows="2" cols="28"></textarea></div>

    <div  class="campoFormulario nomeDeCampo texto textocinzaescuro" >&nbsp;</div>
    <div  class="campoFormulario inputDeCampo" style="text-align:right;" ><input id="Cbutton" class="texto textocinzaescuro"  type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" /></div>
    </form>





<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#Cbutton").click(function() {

      if(validarForm()){
           var Cnome = $("input#Cnome").val(); 
           var CEmpresa = $("input#CEmpresa").val(); 
           var CEmail = $("input#CEmail").val();
           var CCargo = $("input#CCargo").val(); 
           var CTelefone = $("input#CTelefone").val(); 
           var CAssunto = $("textarea#CAssunto").val(); 


          var dataString = 'nome='+ Cnome + '&Empresa=' + CEmpresa + '&Email=' + CEmail + '&Cargo=' + CCargo + '&Telefone=' + CTelefone + '&Assunto=' + CAssunto;
          //alert (dataString);return false;

          $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.myserver.com/index.php/pt/envia", 
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
          $('#frm').remove();
          $('#blocoform').append("<br />Obrigado. <img id='checkmark' src='http://www.myserver.com/public/images/estrutura/ok.gif' /><br />Será contactado brevemente.<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />")
          .hide()
          .fadeIn(1500);

        }
          });
     } 
     return false; 

    });


  });

function validarForm(){
    var error = 0;

    if(!validateNome(document.getElementById("Cnome"))){ error = 1 ;}            
    if(!validateNome(document.getElementById("CEmpresa"))){ error = 1 ;}           
    if(!validateEmail(document.getElementById("CEmail"))){ error = 1 ;}            
        if(!validateNome(document.getElementById("CAssunto"))){ error = 1 ;}            

     if(error == 0){
        //frm.submit();
            return true;
     }else{
            alert('Preencha os campos correctamente.');
            return false;
         }
    }

function validateNome(fld){
        if( fld.value.length == 0  ){
        fld.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFCC';
        //alert('Descrição é um campo obrigatório.');
        return false;
        }else {
           fld.style.background = 'White';
       return true;
        }
}

function trim(s)
{
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}

function validateEmail(fld) {
    var tfld = trim(fld.value);                       
    var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/ ;
    var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;

    if (fld.value == "") {
        fld.style.background = '#FFFFCC';
            //alert('Email é um campo obrigatório.');
        return false;
    } else if (!emailFilter.test(tfld)) {
            //alert('Email inválido.');
        fld.style.background = '#FFFFCC';
        return false;
    } else if (fld.value.match(illegalChars)) {
        fld.style.background = '#FFFFCC';
            //alert('Email inválido.');
        return false;
    } else {
        fld.style.background = 'White';
       return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

---

**FUNCTION ENVIA (email sender):**

```
function envia()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $empresa = $_POST['Empresa'];
        $cargo = $_POST['Cargo'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $telefone = $_POST['Telefone'];
        $assunto = $_POST['Assunto'];

        $mensagem =     "   Nome:".$nome."
    Empresa:".$empresa."
    Cargo:".$cargo."
    Email:".$email."
    Telefone:".$telefone."
    Assunto:".$assunto."";

    $headers = 'From: site@test.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: no-reply' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail('email@test.com', $mensagem, $headers);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify ACTION attribute to your form action="http://www.myserver.com/index.php/pt/envia" , because you are posting to your contact_form.php which I guess is not where you want to post looking at your AJAX code.

2nd edit:

You also need to specify the METHOD attribute of the form. Currently with disabled JavaScript the form is sent via GET and you are looking for POST variables.

```
<form name="frm" id="frm" method="post">
```

Comment: contact_form.php is not a file, it's a function called "envia" inside the "pt" controler

Comment: You are lacking the method="post", by default forms are sent as GET.

Comment: No, there's no need to specify the "action" on the form. The post is made via the `$.ajax` call, and there's clearly a URL supplied there. He also doesn't need the "method" attribute on the `<form>` tag because, again, the post is being made via ajax (and the "type" is clearly specified).

Comment: @Pointy - Exactly my point. So what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: @Pointy he is experiencing the problem when he disables the JavaScript which makes the FORM rely only on HTML and none of his fancy AJAX code is ever called. If there is no method attribute it is sent as GET. The GET is lost when CodeIgniter routes the page and is also not accesible via the $_POST structure. Read his question first.

Comment: Oh.  Well you may be right, @Ivo; I don't understand that part of the question. BUT if there's no "action" attribute, then how can the POST take place at all?  How would he get the email, in other words?

Comment: Yes I Will get the email. But with blank fiels.

Comment: @Pointy he gets the email because if there is no action attribute it will submit to the same page, which I was not initially aware of.

@CodeBurn you are getting the email and it is empty, because if you do not have method="post" the default method used by the form will be GET and you are looking for POST variables in your email send function. Please add the method="post" and test your script without javascript to see that it is working correct.

Comment: @Ivo Sabev - I have done that and also changed $_POST[]
 to $this->input->get_post() witch will search through both the post and get streams for data, looking first in post, and then in get. Now I just have to wait to see if I will get any blank email again from clients.

Comment: @CodeBurn instead of waiting just add echo '<pre>'; print_r($mensagem); exit(); in your envia() function just before mail() and see what happens.

Comment: @Ivo - ah OK, so the URL for the page containing the form is the same as the URL for the "send mail" action.  That makes sense.

Comment: @Ivo - No it's not the same url.

Comment: @CodeBurn then you need to se the action parameter too. Because currently your jQuery sets the appropriate URL and when JavaScript is disabled, because the form doesn't have action will be submitted to the same URL. Set both action and method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var add_member_form=document.getElementById('frm'); 
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: add_member_form.action, data:$('#frm').serialize(),
        success: function(response) {           
            alert(response);
        }
});
```